# How to ignore/skip duplicate (index) on update

Tags: postgresql

I´ve the following table with two columns. The two columns are the combined index key of the table:

```
ID1    ID2
A    X
A    Y
A    Z
B    Z
```

**Now I need to do the following:**

```
UPDATE table SET ID2=X WHERE ID2=Z
```

As the table has a combined key (ID1 + ID2) this leads to a "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" exception cause there is already an "A-X" combination and the update for row "A-Z" violates that key.

**So my question is:**
Is there in Postgres an option to skip on duplicate key? Or do you have any other hint for me?

**Final state of the table should be:**

```
ID1    ID2
A    X
A    Y
B    X
```

Comment: What should be the state of the table after the operation has finished?

Comment: There should be only one A-X left. I´ve added an example above

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of, is to define the primary key as deferrable and then do the update and delete in a single statement:

```
create table t1 (
  id1 text, 
  id2 text, 
  primary key (id1, id2) deferrable
);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
with changed as (
  UPDATE t1 
    SET ID2='X' 
  WHERE ID2='Z'
  returning id1, id2
)
delete from t1
where (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2 from changed)
```

The `DELETE` does not see the new row that has been created by the update, but it sees the "old" one, so only the conflicting one(s) are deleted.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=98e771a7b1b2922d4e55b24e08ac18fc)

Comment: Is it possible to set a key as deferrable for an existing table?

Comment: @Michael: no, not the primary key. You need to drop and re-create it

Answer (score 0):

I realize that under normal conditions we prefer a single statement, but at times 2 may be better. This may very well be one of those. In order to implement the solution by @a_horse_with_no_name it will be necessary to drop and recreate the PK. Not a desirable move. So a 2 statement solution which does not require playing around with the PK.

```
do $$
begin
   delete 
     from tbl t1
    where t1.id2 = 'Z'
      and exists (
                   select null
                     from tbl t2 
                    where t1.id1 = t2.id1
                      and t2.id2 = 'X'
                 );

update tbl 
   set id2 = 'X'
 where id2 = 'Z';

 end; 
 $$;
```

The advantage of the DO block being that if for some reason the second statement fails, the action of the first is rolled back. So the database remains in a consistent state.